# React fill all space as much as possible but #root fixed height and width

Tags: html, css, reactjs, web, frontend

I am using React for my project and I want my container div fill all space as much as possible

[image]

So my container div has a className called `stories` but it has a parent div has id called `root` with a fixed height is 640 and width is 360 and this is my css of div `stories`:

```
.stories {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(black, #1a1a1a);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}
```

how can I get rid of that, thank you so much and have a good day

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me. With `width` also set to `100vw`.

https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-wing-ku2xd?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: thanks, I tried, but it not worked, it is not changing anything